# Angular $http get method does not send correct data to server

Tags: angularjs

I am new at angular. I use angular.js and webapi. I have a request like below.

```
[HttpGet]
public RecordDTO[] GetMyFiles(UserClass usr,int uId,int fId)
{
}
```

my webapi call is like this. UserClass parameter is a class that has two string field(name,password). My angular code is like below.

```
$scope.GetMyFiles= function () {
   var user = { Name:'xx',Password:'xx' };
    var data = {usr:user, uId: 11, fId: 56};
    $http({
        url:"../api/Home/GetMyFiles",
        method: 'GET',
        //headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        params: data
    })
     .success(function (data) {
         alert("OK");
     })
    .error(function (data) {
       alert("error");
    });
};
```

My problem is UserClass is null. It takes uId and fId parameters, but first parameter comes null.
How can I correct this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this WebApi method signature expects as URL? Please post a URL that would allow passing a user, a uId and a fId to that method.

Comment: I try also Post. But this time, It does not go to webapi call. It gives error.

Comment: What type of content is your back end expecting? Angularjs default conent-type is 'application-json'.

Comment: I am almost sure that `url:"../api/Home/GetMyFiles",` is wrong. Try to paste absolute path to this controller, for example: `url:"127.0.0.1:8000/api/Home/GetMyFiles",`

Comment: @infaustus if the url was wrong, uId and fId would be null too

Comment: what is your usr variable and UserClass parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

As the default `content-type` for `$http` is `JSON`, check what your service is attending. If its `JSON`, you should `stringify` your data to pass them to your webapi :

```
params: JSON.stringify(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to **SEND** data to the server, you should make a `$http.post` call. I think the problem because you are not specifiying the `content-type` of the header. 
please try this:

```
     $http.post('/api/Home/GetMyFiles', data , {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;' }
        }
            ).success(function(data) })
                       .error(function(err){});
```

Tell me if it works, and if you need any help let me know. Happy Coding. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change `$http` method from `GET` to `POST`. Also change `params: data` to `data: data`. I tried this code in my local PC and it works correctly.

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]    
    public RecordDTO[] GetMyFiles(UserClass usr, int uId, int fId )
    {
    }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $http({
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',                    
      data: data                   
     })
       .success(function (data) {
            alert("OK");
       })
       .error(function (data) {
            alert("error");
       });
```